# Running command line utility inside client-side script?

Tags: html, command-line, client-side

Is there some way to run a command line tool from a client-side script?  I want to do something like this:

```
myutility -flag1 -flag2 inputfile outputfile
```

with a script in the head of an html file.  Is there a way to do it, preferably with JS in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That script, myutility needs to be compatible with the server machine your webserver is running on, as well as the script needs to have the correct execution rights. Let me know what kind of script it is so that I can help further, is it a bash script you are trying to run? Perhaps you could do that within your server side language, ie php to make things easier?